# make a query select like username and trigger modal to hide - Ajax & Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I trigger modal hide after the ajax successfully get the data from the server. right now my problem is the modal is not closing even after I make a query on the server side, it might me my ajax calling is wrong but tried this code and it does not even work please see my code below.

here is the value

```
<textarea id="scanned-QR" name="search"></textarea>
```

here is the modal

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the var value that I fetch from the textarea value

```
var query = $('#scanned-QR').val();
    fetch_customer_data(query);


$(document).on('keyup', '#scanned-QR', function(){
      var query = $(this).val();
      fetch_customer_data(query);
    });
```

and here is my ajax call

```
    function fetch_customer_data(query = '') 
    {

      $.ajax({
        url:"select.php",
        method: 'GET',
        data:{query:query},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
            $("#exampleModal").removeClass("in");
            $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
            $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
            $('body').css('padding-right', '');
            $("#exampleModal").hide();
        },
        error:function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
      });
    }
```

**so the output is :** after I `keyup` then the textarea value will compare to the database value if it is `LIKE` or the same value, then if it is the same value. success ajax must execute the following lines.

lastly, my database connect and my select query

**select.php**

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysqli_select_db($link, "test");

  $query = $_GET['query'];

  $res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username LIKE '$admin%' ");

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two mistakes,

1) replace `$('#exampleModal').hide();` to `$('#exampleModalLong').hide();`

2) you are not returning `json` from your `select.php`

In `select.php` add this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $respose = array('status'=>'1');//1 for success
    echo json_encode($respose );        
} else {
    $respose = array('status'=>'0');//0 for fail
    echo json_encode($respose );        
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

In Ajax: add this

```
success:function(data) {
   if(data.status == '1'){
       $("#exampleModalLong").removeClass("in");
       $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
       $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
       $('body').css('padding-right', '');
       $("#exampleModalLong").hide();
   }
},
```

Comment: hi i tried your code sir it seems logical but the result is still the same :(

Comment: did you check you console panel ? is there any error?